# Wait until all ajax queries in each() function are finished using $.when()

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

How can I run callback() after checking that there is no error in the ajax queries included in the $.each() function?

```
var resp_error = false;
$(".items").each(function() {
    ajax_item($(this)).done(function(resp){
        if (resp.val == 0)    return (resp_error = true);
    });
});
if (!resp_error)    callback();
```

Where ajax_item(item) is a deferred ajax query:

```
function ajax_item(item) {
    return $.ajax({
       ...
    });
};
```

`val` is returned by the ajax query and triggers an error (`resp_error`) when `val = 0`.

I believe that the best way is to use $.when(), but I don't find the way to code it?

Comment: I'm kind of confused. What is ajax_item? Are you trying to make an ajax call on every item named items?

Comment: It is an ajax query: function ajax_item(item) { return $.ajax({...});

Comment: OK, I was on the jQuery api documentation and didn't see that anywhere. Guess it's special lol

Comment: I think what is messing me all up is I usually see a jQuery ajax call start like this $.ajax.

Comment: It's because your code isn't written well. Can't help you if I or others can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it!

```
var resp_error = false;
var ajax_calls = [];
$(".items").each(function() {
    ajax_calls.push(ajax_item($(this)).done(function(resp){
       if (resp.val == 0)    return (resp_error = true);
    }));
});
$.when.apply($, ajax_calls).then(function() {
    if (!resp_error)    callback();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  // place code to be executed on completion of last outstanding ajax call here
});
```

Comment: I believe that $.ajaxStop can be affected by other ajax calls, not only by the ones in the each function.